# How to pass state value from one class to another in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to pass state value from one component to another in reactjs. As you can see i am trying to put value into input. Value is declared in one component and has to pass another component. Showvalue is the component where i declare a state values. And i want it into input value

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Showvalue extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            values: 'dsfg'
        }

    }
    render(){
        return (<div>{this.state.values}</div>);
    }
}
class Showinput extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value:this.props.values
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <input value={this.state.value}></input>
        );
    }
}

function Element(){
    return(
        <div>
        <Showvalue />
        <Showinput />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(

    <Element/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element() has to be a Component with state and the value has to be stored in upper state (lifted state). IE:

```js
Class Element extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 'dsfg'
        }

    }
    
    onChange = (val) => this.setState({ value: val })
    
    render(){
        return (<div>
        <Showvalue value={this.state.value} />
        <Showinput value={this.state.value} changeValue={this.onChange}/>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Inputs from './InputValue.js'
class Showvalue extends Component{
         constructor(props){
         super(props)
         this.state={
             message1: 'hey'
         }
     this.ImportStateValue=this.ImportStateValue.bind(this) 
     ImportStateValue()={
           return this.state.message1
     }

    render(){
               return(
                       <Input Datalink={this.ImportStateValue}>
               )

    }

}
//InputValue.js
class InputValue extends Component{
   constructor(){
      super()
      this.state{
          message2: null;
      }
      this.SetValue=this.SetValue.bind(this)

   }
    async SetValue(){
    await const val=this.props.Datalink()
    this.setState({
        message2: val
    })
 }

 render(){
             return(
                    <button onClick={this.SetValue}></button>
             )
 }
```

}

First You must initialize all the state values in class ShowValue. And the write a function which returns the sate value and pass that function using a prop to the class InputValue. And assign that prop to a variable of class Inputvalue. And assign that variable value as your state value using Setstate. You can test values using consol.log(this.state)